# C# get fsmo roles from ad

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, domaincontroller

**Is there a way to get FSMO roles using C# from active directory?** Even if possible with LDAP query will work.

There is lot of VB Script code given on lots of blogs. But not C#.

**And how to find a DC is PDC or not?**

Thanks

Comment: System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain dom = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetCurrentDomain();
            System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DomainController pdcdc = dom.PdcRoleOwner;
            foreach (ActiveDirectoryRole role in pdcdc.Roles)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", role.ToString());
            }

above code will give me fsmo role type but will not tell whether it is set or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it will be tough job to find this but end up very easy. I am posting code in case in future someone need this.

```
System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain dom = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetCurrentDomain();
System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DomainController pdcdc = dom.PdcRoleOwner;
foreach (System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DomainController dc in dom.DomainControllers)
                {
                    foreach (ActiveDirectoryRole role in dc.Roles)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("dc : {0} role : {1}", dc.Name,role.ToString());
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask far an LDAP way to find the fives *Flexible Single Master Operation* (FSMO) role from Active-Directory. They can be found looking for the attribute `fsmoRoleOwner` in different naming contexts of the Active Directory. You'll find here under 3 LDAP searchs written in C#. Be careful the code is not so clean it's just a kind of proof of concept.

A good source is [Determining FSMO Role Holders](http://www.petri.co.il/determining_fsmo_role_holders.htm).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  /* Retreiving RootDSE informations
   */
  string ldapBase = "LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/";
  string sFromWhere = ldapBase + "rootDSE";
  DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(sFromWhere, "dom\\jpb", "pwd");
  string defaultNamingContext = root.Properties["defaultNamingContext"][0].ToString();
  string schemaNamingContext = root.Properties["schemaNamingContext"][0].ToString();
  string configurationNamingContext = root.Properties["configurationNamingContext"][0].ToString();

  /* Search the 3 domain FSMO roles
   */
  sFromWhere = ldapBase + defaultNamingContext;
  DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry(sFromWhere, "dom\\jpb", "pwd");

  DirectorySearcher dsLookForDomain = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
  dsLookForDomain.Filter = "(fsmoRoleOwner=*)";
  dsLookForDomain.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
  dsLookForDomain.PropertiesToLoad.Add("fsmoRoleOwner");
  dsLookForDomain.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");

  SearchResultCollection srcDomains = dsLookForDomain.FindAll();
  foreach (SearchResult sr in srcDomains)
  {
    /* For each root look for the groups containing my user
     */
    string fsmoRoleOwner = sr.Properties["fsmoRoleOwner"][0].ToString();
    string distinguishedName = sr.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString();
    Regex srvNameRegEx = new Regex("^CN=NTDS Settings,CN=(.*),CN=Servers,.*$");
    Match found = srvNameRegEx.Match(fsmoRoleOwner);

    if (distinguishedName == defaultNamingContext)
      Console.WriteLine("PDC is {0}", found.Groups[1].Value);
    else if (distinguishedName.Contains("RID Manager"))
      Console.WriteLine("RID Manager is {0}", found.Groups[1].Value);
    else
      Console.WriteLine("Infrastructure Manager is {0}", found.Groups[1].Value);
  }

  /* Search the schema FSMO role
  */
  sFromWhere = ldapBase + schemaNamingContext;
  deBase = new DirectoryEntry(sFromWhere, "dom\\jpb", "pwd");

  dsLookForDomain = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
  dsLookForDomain.Filter = "(fsmoRoleOwner=*)";
  dsLookForDomain.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
  dsLookForDomain.PropertiesToLoad.Add("fsmoRoleOwner");
  dsLookForDomain.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");

  srcDomains = dsLookForDomain.FindAll();
  foreach (SearchResult sr in srcDomains)
  {
    /* For each root look for the groups containing my user
     */
    string fsmoRoleOwner = sr.Properties["fsmoRoleOwner"][0].ToString();
    string distinguishedName = sr.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString();
    Regex srvNameRegEx = new Regex("^CN=NTDS Settings,CN=(.*),CN=Servers,.*$");
    Match found = srvNameRegEx.Match(fsmoRoleOwner);

    if (distinguishedName.Contains("Schema"))
      Console.WriteLine("Schema Manager is {0}", found.Groups[1].Value);
  }

  /* Search the domain FSMO role
  */
  sFromWhere = ldapBase + configurationNamingContext;
  deBase = new DirectoryEntry(sFromWhere, "dom\\jpb", "pwd");

  dsLookForDomain = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
  dsLookForDomain.Filter = "(fsmoRoleOwner=*)";
  dsLookForDomain.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
  dsLookForDomain.PropertiesToLoad.Add("fsmoRoleOwner");
  dsLookForDomain.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");

  srcDomains = dsLookForDomain.FindAll();
  foreach (SearchResult sr in srcDomains)
  {
    /* For each root look for the groups containing my user
     */
    string fsmoRoleOwner = sr.Properties["fsmoRoleOwner"][0].ToString();
    string distinguishedName = sr.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString();
    Regex srvNameRegEx = new Regex("^CN=NTDS Settings,CN=(.*),CN=Servers,.*$");
    Match found = srvNameRegEx.Match(fsmoRoleOwner);

    if (distinguishedName.Contains("Partitions"))
      Console.WriteLine("Domain Manager is {0}", found.Groups[1].Value);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I figured it out and posted my solution below.